# Running a batch file on Kid3 ID3 MP3 tagger

Tags: batch-file, id3v2

I finally gave up after 120 hours of not finding a .NET or javascript/jquery plugin that can read and write to a COMPRESSED custom user frame (TXXX) in ID3v2 MP3 audio file.

UltraID3Lib: cannot read or write COMPRESSED Frames (last updated 2009, author Mitchell S. Honnert fell off face of the earth).

ID3Lib-sharp: cannot read or write COMPRESSED Frames (last updated 2012)

JavaScript-ID3-Reader: can return bytes but it's mostly the wrong bytes. Cannot write anything.

I cannot use the multitudes of Node.js or PHP scripts for my project so they are out of the question.

The only code I found that can read and write compress frames is Kid3.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/kid3/

However, it is written in C (I don't know that) and uses third party frameworks since it was not built in windows. The Command  program required 13MB of support dlls, QMs, and whatevers.

I have no choice at his point but to try and use it's separate command program kid3-cli.exe

So here's my question:

Here is the way to read a TXXX frame using the program at the command prompt.
"71F3-15-FOO58A77" is the name of the TXXX frame and the "2" gets the text value it holds:

```
cd "C:\mp3folder"
select "test.mp3"
get "71F3-15-FOO58A77" "2"
export "clipboard" "CSV unquoted" "2"
```

QUESTION: HOW DO I use a Batch file to run these commands?
According to kid3 documents. It shows using -c as grouped commands. Windows cmd (or the program) on windows does know what -c is.

Example: I double click the batch file and it should:

1. start the program
2. sent the program (not cmd) the above 4 lines
3. each must be executed separately.

Sounds simple, but I can't get it to even execute one of the programs code after starting.

Any ideas? and and can someone write a ID3 tag program that can read and write COMPRESSED TXXX tags without using node.js, PHP or a server in Windows.

I will buy them a beer because I'm really a (cheap) designer by trade and a pert-time programmer only when I have too.

```
  Here is a zip file of a COMPRESSED TXXX Frame in test.mp3 to test:
  [http://robbiestewart.ca/test.zip][1]
```

1. Download Kid3 and use its windows GUI (kid3.exe) to view the custom user frame (TXXX).
2. Run the included kid3-cli.exe to do the same at the command prompt.
3. Try to do the same in a batch file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the help file, you should be able to use the command
`kid3-cli -c 'cd "C:\mp3folder"' -c 'select "test.mp3"' -c 'get "71F3-15-F0058A77" "2"' -c 'export "clipboard" "CSV unquoted" "2"'`

I ran it on the file you provided and seven tabs followed by `0:00.00` were put on my clipboard, but the value of the TXXX field indicated by the GUI was output to my command prompt.

Comment: I running windows cmd.exe  What are you running? Can you give me a MS cmd  batch file example?

Comment: I'm also running windows cmd.exe. Just take the code I posted and put it in your batch file. If you want the output put into a file, add `>>output.txt` to the end of the line.

Comment: My mistake, I was running the kid3-cli then pasting the code in, as opposed to running cmd first then pasted the code to start kid3-cli. You are correct.